# What is the status on dynarrays?

Tags: c++, c++14, dynamic-arrays, dynarray

[gcc 4.9](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) now has support for [n3696 (Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html). [n3662](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3662.html#Solution) says:

> In [N3497](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3497.html) Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage
>   duration, Jens Maurer proposes arrays with runtime bound. These arrays
>   are to std::dynarray as normal fixed-size arrays are to std::array.

In this [mailing list](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-06/msg00045.html), Jonathan Wakely says:

> We should add a C++14 status table to the manual but in the meantime
>   here's a quick summary of the library status.
>
> ...
>
> These ones are missing:
>
> - N3672 A proposal to add a utility class to represent optional objects
> - N3655 TransformationTraits Redux
> - N3662 C++ Dynamic Arrays
> - N3644 Null Forward Iterators
>
> The traits one is simple but a bit tedious and the iterators one
>   probably only affects debug mode, but the other two are substantial
>   pieces of work.  Is anyone planning on working on  or
>    yet?

However, n3662 also says:

> **Instead of adopting C variable-length arrays** we propose to
>   define a new facility for arrays where the number of elements is bound
>   at construction. We call these dynamic arrays, dynarray.

I can't seem to find `dynarray` using a quick CTRL+F on the `gcc` pages. So is `dynarray` going to be implemented soon, and will `variable length arrays` stay or will it disappear?

Comment: [N3497](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3497.html) works fine for me (wrt "dead link"). Oh, hehe, that's a typo in n3662. They've linked n3467.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::dynarray` was intended to go with c++14 at first. However, it was later decided that `std::dynarray` would be moved to an "Array TS" which may also include some `std::array_view` class. The main reason is that the committee did not agree on some points concerning heap-allocation versus stack-allocation in some cases (what if you try to allocate an `std::dynarray` with `new`). Therefore, it was decided that it would be delayed. There are still some [ongoing discussions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3810.pdf) about what should be done.

The class won't be ready for C++14. It will probably come with the Arrays TS or C++17.

**Update:** `std::dynarray` wasn't in C++14, won't be in C++17, the Arrays TS has been discontinued, so there probably won't be anything close to `std::dynarray` in the standard before long. If I understand the current position of the standard correctly, rather than magical runtime-sized arrays, the committee would rather come up with a general solution for runtime-sized classes, but [every](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4188.pdf) [suggestion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4025.pdf) so far has been rejected.